# VaryByCustom not working for session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, outputcache, varybyparam

I'm using output cache for a web site with login system. I have global pages which can be accessed by every user. These pages are cached and also use a master page.

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="3600" VaryByParam="none" VaryByCustom="userid" %>
```

I'm storing user login details in a session. My global.asax file is here:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    string result = String.Empty;
    if (arg == "userid")
    {
        object o = Session["UserID"];
        if (o != null) { result = o.ToString(); }
    }
    else { result = base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg); }
    return result;
}
```

I have a panel in master page which is visible for authenticated users. When a user logins and views public page A another guest user also sees authenticated user panel on page A. If guest first view page A then authenticated user does not see panel on page A.

What part of my code is wrong? I'm using [VaryByCustom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ecf4420.aspx) for first time.

**EDIT**

I've modified my global.asax like this but nothing is written in the text file:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    string result = String.Empty;

    FileInfo t = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("App_Data\\debug.txt"));
    StreamWriter Tex = t.AppendText();
    Tex.WriteLine("GetVaryByCustomString: " + arg);

    if (arg == "userid")
    {
        object o = Session["UserID"];
        if (o != null) { result = o.ToString(); }

        Tex.WriteLine("Checked UserID: " + o + Tex.NewLine);            
    }
    else { result = base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg); }

    Tex.Close();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: OK, I've found that I cannot access current session variable "Session state is not available in this context.". Trying to fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think that probably the Session["UserID"] for some reason always return null / or some times return null, even if the user is authenticated.

Double check that you set it before this function ask for it.

Comment: I see that the session variable is changed but problem is GetVaryByCustomString is not fired/work properly I think

Comment: @hasanGursoy Yes somewhere there is the problem, but if the Function is called, then the session parameter is not set.

Comment: Tried everything but it seems **Session** is not available when it's requested by cached page varybycustom, it only works on user controls.

Comment: @HasanGursoy So I have right about the Session !. Try just to get the cookie of the session. Is the same think as the one you try.

Comment: I can't use cookies for user authentication. So I've disabled caching at all pages.